# Positive/Negative signs are stuck between leading zeros and the number. How do I make the signs move to the beginning?

Tags: c

Right now, I am using MPLAB X IDE 3.45 and for an assignment I need to print out a temperature table with the required conditions. I am able to satisfy all of them except one. When I try to pad the numbers with 0s, **plus** and **negative** signs **override zeros**. For example, they look like **00-7** or **0+123**. However, I would like to be able to print them as **-007** or **+0123.**

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
// **** Include libraries here ****
// Standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>

//Class specific libraries
#include "BOARD.h"

// Microchip libraries
#include <xc.h>

// User libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    BOARD_Init();
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Your code goes in between this comment and the following one with asterisks.
 **************************************************************************************************/
    // Declare Variables
    float fahr, celcius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    // Initialize Variables
    lower = 0; // lower limit of temperature
    upper = 300; // upper limit
    step = 20; // step size
    fahr = lower;

    // Print out table
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celcius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
        printf("%7.1f %04.0f\n", (double)fahr, (double)celcius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Your code goes in between this comment and the preceding one with asterisks.
 **************************************************************************************************/

    // Returning from main() is bad form in embedded environments. So we sit and spin.
    while (1);
}
```

**Output of the function**

```
Fahr      Celc
0.0 0-18
20.0 00-7
40.0 0004
60.0 0016
80.0 0027
100.0 0038
120.0 0049
140.0 0060
160.0 0071
180.0 0082
200.0 0093
220.0 0104
240.0 0116
260.0 0127
280.0 0138
300.0 0149
```

Note: I am using the simulator for this part.

Comment: I suspect your `printf()` is faulty.

Comment: `"%+04.0f"` _should_ do it for you.

Comment: @chux When I try to use **"%+04.0f"**, I get the same problem. However, this time **plus sign** also becomes a part of the problem too :/

Comment: Adding the _exact_ output is more informative than only describing the output.   What was the exact complete format used?  What was the exact textual output?  Some samples please.

Comment: `printf()` is faulty.  Output should be be `0.0 -018    20.0 -007 ...
  280.0 +138   300.0 +149`.  Either use [alternate code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41669675/2410359) that works around the problem and/or advise the compiler manufacturer of the defect. (Tip make sure your have the most recent library)  Another idea, just report Kelvin, I'm _absolutely_ certain there are no negative values to worry about.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the `printf()` implementation on your system:

> **7.21.6.1: The `fprintf` function**
>
> 6 The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> `+`   The result of a signed conversion always begins with a plus or minus sign. (It begins with a sign only when a negative value is converted if this flag is not specified.)
>
> `0`   For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the `0` and `-` flags both appear, the `0` flag is ignored.

`%04.0f` should pad the number with leading `0`s after the negative sign and should not output a `+` unless you also pass the `+` flag as in:

```
printf("%7.1f %+04.0f\n", (double) fahr, (double) celcius);
```

Comment: I also think that there is a problem with the printf function implementation but I don't know why because I am using the library that **microchip provides**. I guess, I will ask the professor for help. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

OP's `printf()` fails to print floating point numbers with the desired format.

*Sometimes* the compiler/binary is faulty per specification [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669703/2410359)

Below is an integer only solution as a work around.

```
  // Declare Variables
  int fahr;
  int milli_celcius;
  int lower, upper, step;

  // Initialize Variables
  lower = 0; // lower limit of temperature
  upper = 300; // upper limit
  step = 20; // step size
  fahr = lower;

  // Print out table
  while (fahr <= upper) {
    printf("%5d.0 ", fahr);
    milli_celcius = ((fahr - 32) * 5 * 1000) / 9;
    // round to nearest whole degree;
    int celcius = milli_celcius < 0 ? 
        (milli_celcius - 1000 / 2) / 1000 :  
        (milli_celcius + 1000 / 2) / 1000;
    printf("%+04d  Ref:%f\n", celcius, (fahr - 32.0) * 5 / 9.0);
    fahr = fahr + step;
  }
```

Output

```
    0.0 -018  Ref:-17.777778 
   20.0 -007  Ref:-6.666667 
   ...
  280.0 +138  Ref:137.777778 
  300.0 +149  Ref:148.888889
```

Comment: I am outside right now but when I go back home I will try it and let everyone know if this solves my problems as the feedback may help many others who are having a similar problem. Thanks for all of your help by the way :)